# Symfony2 form trying to connect to DB on submission

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a form in Symfony2 where a user is submitting info for their credit card. The form renders perfectly fine intially, but on submission, I get the error `"An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".`

My code for the controller action:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class: PaymentController
 *
 * This controller is used to serve an iframe that contains a form for
 * a person's credit card information.
 *
 * @see Controller
 */
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * indexAction
     *
     * Display a form for a user to enter their credit card information
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function subscribeAction(Request $request)
    {
        $ccForm = new CreditCard();
        $form = $this->createForm(new CreditCardType(), $ccForm);

        //This function attempts to connect to DB on form submission 
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        //Never gets here

        if ($form->isValid()) {

        } 


        //render view here (this part works fine)
    }
}
```

My question is why does `$form->handleRequest($request)` attempt to connect to the DB? From the stacktrace it looks like the Validator classes call the Doctrine ORM and it's trying to connect to a db there. I don't want it to do that and I simply want to keep the data in memory and make some API calls with it.

I have no metadata on my entity class that would suggest that Doctrine should try to save it to the db. Any ideas?

Edit:
If I delete the doctrine configuration from `app/config/config.yml` like below then I can access my form object perfectly fine after `$form-isValid()`

```
# Doctrine Configuration
#doctrine:
#    dbal:
#        driver:   "%database_driver%"
#        host:     "%database_host%"
#        port:     "%database_port%"
#        dbname:   "%database_name%"
#        user:     "%database_user%"
#        password: "%database_password%"
#        charset:  UTF8
#        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
#        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
#        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
#        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
#        #   3. Uncomment next line:
#        #     path:     "%database_path%"
#
#    orm:
#        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
#        auto_mapping: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you creating an `CreditCardType()` object, it will call your entity including doctrine and connection used for checking the object. You can try to create manual the form in controller like this :

```
public function subscribeAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createCreditCardForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {             
        $entity = $form->getData();
        // do what you want with the $entity
    } 
    //render view here 
}

private function createCreditCardForm()
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()->setAction($this->generateUrl('route_here_if_needed'))
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('your_field', 'type')
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

If you can do this successfully, then you can try to modify your type and without creating a `CreditCardType()` object.

Comment: Can you clarify on this? Creating the CreditCard() object invokes Doctrine somehow? I was following the example at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes to make the form reusable. It's pretty huge - it includes a country field and state field so I don't want to clutter a controller with that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean `CreditCardType()` Object. (I edited it) Your type can not become ambiguous. If you creating a Type for updating, insert (connecting to database). You can not make it special for some case to avoid database connection (*as far as I know*) unless you make an another type or form special for this case. I've given you an example how to retrieve data from it. @IgorPantovic explained it well.

Comment: So if I build my form using $this->createForm() form within a controller and using a class that extends AbstractType it will by default attempt to do some sort of mapping with the database and Doctrine? Any example of this in the docs?

Comment: No, as long you are not connect any of field or default options with entity which naturally have mapped data to database. I'm sorry, I can not find any docs about it, maybe you can do some research about it. But as long your form connecting to a field that using your entity either with `createForm()` or `createFormBuilder()` it will require database connection. You can see how this works in step by step and figure it out, why you need database connection for creating a form using your entity here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: After reading the docs I'm still not sure why it forces a db connection if I haven't even added metadata to the entity class for mapping to the database. It seems odd to tightly couple the creation of a form with an entity with the database. Especially since all the docs show how you can persist to the database after you submit but say nothing (that I could find) about why you would need a db connection before that. Thanks for help. I'm going to try your version and then http://stackoverflow.com/a/14903672/1174374 if that fails.

Answer (score 1):

No, `$form->handleRequest` does not connect to DB explicitly **but** it **[does fire form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html)**. Depending on what subforms you have on your `CreditCardType`, one of them could be connecting to database.

Comment: Hm I don't have any form events attached. Also no subforms, just a basic form with 7 or 8 fields and a submit button.

Comment: @CalebTaylor : Including complete information in your question will be better ;)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to avoid dumping a ton of lines of code. I was hoping it was a beginner Symfony2 mistake that would be easily identified ;)